# Mathematica can't solve system of equations but doesn't show error

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I try to solve a system of equations:

```
m2 a2y == -g m2 + n,
m1 a1x ==  Sin[θ] n Exp[μ θ],
m1 a1y == -g m1 + Cos[θ] n Exp[μ θ],
   a2y ==  Sqrt[a1x^2 + a1y^2] Sin[θ - ArcTan[a1y/a1x]]
```

for `a1x, a1y, a2y` and `n`. When I use `Solve[]` function it doesn't do anything for a looong time, but doesn't show any error. Is this system unsolvable or does Mathematica just need a lot of time to solve it?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to try to solve this? It could be something as simple as a typo, but without code it will be difficult to diagnose. Have you tried `Solve` on a very simple system that you can verify by hand to make sure you're using the command correctly, for instance?

Comment: My code: 'equ = {m2 a2y == -g m2 + n,
  m1 a1x == Sin[\[Theta]] n Exp[\[Mu] \[Theta]],
  m1 a1y == -g m1 + Cos[\[Theta]] n Exp[\[Mu] \[Theta]],
  a2y == Sqrt[a1x^2 + a1y^2] Sin[\[Theta] - ArcTan[a1y/a1x]]}; Solve[equ, {a1x, a1y, a2y, n}]'

Answer (score 1):

It can be done much quicker if you break it up by noticing the first 3 equations are fairly simple.

```
eq1 = m2 a2y == -g m2 + n;
eq2 = m1 a1x == Sin[\[Theta]] n Exp[\[Mu] \[Theta]];
eq3 = m1 a1y == -g m1 + Cos[\[Theta]] n Exp[\[Mu] \[Theta]];
eq4 = a2y == Sqrt[a1x^2 + a2x^2] Sin[\[Theta] - ArcTan[a1y/a1x]];

sol = Solve[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, {a2y, a1x, a1y}] // Flatten
(*{a2y -> (n - g m2)/m2, a1x -> (n E^(θ μ) Sin[θ])/m1,
  a1y -> (n E^(θ μ) Cos[θ] - g m1)/m1}*)

a2y = a2y /. sol
a1x = a1x /. sol
a1y = a1y /. sol

Solve[eq4, a2x] // Simplify
```

We get 2 fairly lengthy answers(plus and minus) that I will not post here, but the result is returned immediately.

Comment: OP want find: `{a1x, a1y, a2y, n}` not `{a1x, a1y, a2y, a2x}` ?

Comment: I had a wrong variable in the last equation (a2x instead of a1y), and as it worked perfectly before, now it doesn't.